# Prevent the keyUp event

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I bind `keyDown`, `keyPress` and `keyUp` events to a text input. I need to prevent `keyUp` from firing on certain cases that I can trap in `keyDown` or `keyPress`.

So far I've tried `preventDefault` and `stopPropagation` but none worked so far.
Is it possible that I prevent the `keyUp` event from firing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cannot prevent one event from the other

subscribe to the keyUp event and prevent it from there using preventDefault

Comment: So, I cannot intervin to the chaining in any way through the provided event structure? :(
Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: yes, no way to say "don't fire that other event". Instead use some tracking variable to see if the keyDown was already handled and you should ignore the keyUp (if you wanted to prevent it for yourself), or prevent the keyUp event from its handler if you want to prevent the default (browser's) behavior

Comment: It's pretty much what I already do. I was just trying to figure out of a more 'proper' way.
Here's what I actually do :)
https://github.com/ptheofan/cool.inputFilter/blob/master/jquery.cool.inputFilter.js

Comment: this is actually the proper way - events are independent in their nature. your code looks good, I should say